# Why does the program exit when I enter a value into it?

Tags: python

Here's the program. The program converts from Kilogram to Pounds and vice-versa.

```
pref = input("Hello, This is a program to convert 1. Mass, 2. Length, 3. Speed, 4. Temperature, 5. Currency and 6. Date \n Enter your option in NUMBER")

if pref == 1. or 1:
     pref1 = input("1. Kg to lb \n 2. Lb to kgs")

if pref1 == 1:
    Kgs = input("Enter weight in Kg")
    Lbs = float(Kgs)*2.20462
    print(str(Lbs)) 
elif pref1 == 2:
    Lbs = input("Enter weight in lbs")
    Kgs = float(Lbs)/2.20462
    print(str(Kgs))
else:
    exit()
```

However, it exits when I type a value into the program for the second time, i.e. when the program asks the user to enter their preference of whether they want to convert from Pound to Kilogram or vice-versa.\

Could someone please point out my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get your input, the type of it will be `str`.
Since you are only comparing to `int`s, you will end up in your else clause.
Try converting the result of `input` to `int`

e.g.

```
pref = int(input("Hello, This is a program to convert 1. Mass, 2. Length, 3. Speed, 4. Temperature, 5. Currency and 6. Date \n Enter your option in NUMBER"))

if (pref == 1.) or (pref == 1):
     pref1 = int(input("1. Kg to lb \n 2. Lb to kgs"))
....
```

As pointed out in the comments, you also should check `if (pref == 1)` instead of `if pref == 1. or 1` since `pref` is converted to an integer in my answer anyway

Comment: Still wrong. Python sees `if pref == 1. or 1:` as `if (pref == 1.) or 1:` and that will always evaluate to `True`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `pref`, when received from `input`, is a string and not an integer.

Change all your if statements to :

```
if int(pref1) == ...
```

That would solve the problem.